# Ensuing or Resulting

Tags: word-choice

What option fits best in the following question please?

An obstacle had been placed in the middle of the road and the ___________ accident was blamed on it.

a. following

b. ensuing

c. resulting

---

I think it is not following otherwise the sentence should have been written conversely.Oxford Dictionary says ensuing and following synonym.

> The guards returned fire, and the ensuing gunfight lasted all
>   day.[(MacMillan)](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/ensuing)

This example is so similar to the sentence.

Comment: 'Resulting' doesn't fit, 'ensuing' and 'following' mean the same thing here, but I'd not use either of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following is fine.  Says who? [The World Affairs Council](https://www.world-affairs.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/Post_Tsunami_FULL-Packet-FOR-WEB.pdf):

> The Great East Japan Earthquake of March 11 and the **following** accident at the Fukushima Daiichi nuclear power plant

Ensuing is fine.  Says who?  [The Baltimore Sun](http://www.baltimoresun.com/explore/harford/news/ph-ag-highway-medical-death-0314-20120313-story.html):

> The investigation is ongoing but police believe Mr. Farley's death and the **ensuing** accident were caused by a medical emergency.

Resulting is fine.  Says who?  [The Harvard Business Review](https://hbr.org/2010/05/the-visualization-trap):

> Some people examined normal traffic conditions; others saw or read about a driver error but not the **resulting** accident

Personally I like ensuing, because, how often do you get to say ensuing?

Ensuing!